# Angular ng-bind-html and ng-mouseover don't work (don't appears in code)

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I try to add some code with `ng-bind-html` with included `ng-mouseover`. But the `ng-mouseover` part didn't appear (didn't work) in the code

Sample from angular plunker and add my piece of code:

> ng-mouseover="test($event)"

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myHTML =
       'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
       '<a ng-mouseover="test($event)" href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';

    $scope.test = function(event) {
      console.log(event);
    }

  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/gp3Z50TJqvEfOFGrpYCT?p=preview

The $scope.test() function was never fired. There is no event appears on mouseover above this small link.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write custom directive that evaluates html within scope.

Comment: Any link or sample to do so?